# AWS CloudFormation Ethereum: The following resource(s) failed to create: [ServiceAutoScalingGroup]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, blockchain

I got these errors:

- The following resource(s) failed to create: [ServiceAutoScalingGroup]
- Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.

[image]

when I tried to create the Ethereum Network with CloudFormation from [this instruction](https://aws.amazon.com/blockchain/templates/getting-started/).

[image]

I checked the template but there seems to be no error in it.

The template URL: https://aws-blockchain-templates-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ethereum/templates/latest/ethereum-network.template.yaml

Before that, I already prepared resources for this stack following [this instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-template-getting-started-prerequisites.html), including:

- 1 VPC with 2 private subnets and 2 public subnets
- 2 security groups for EC2 and ALB
- 1 group with 1 user + 2 IAM roles for EC2 and ECS
- 1 bastion host

These errors mean AWS couldn't send a signal to my ASG. I think some setups weren't in the docs.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the template? What is your current setup? Sadly your question lacks details.

Comment: @Marcin I added the template URL to the question and the current setup was provided at the end of the question. What detail do you need?